# How to hide a session parameters in Swagger with Springfox

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "获取打卡信息", notes = "获取打卡信息")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{mPhone}/{mPassword}/{date}")
@ApiImplicitParams({ 
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "mPhone", value = "手机号", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="13268690268",paramType="Path"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "mPassword", value = "密码", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="111111",paramType="Path"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "date", value = "日期", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="2017-07-04",paramType="Path"),
        @ApiImplicitParam(name = "httpSession", value = "Session", required = false)})
public @ResponseBody String getSignInfo(@PathVariable String mPhone, @PathVariable String mPassword,
        @PathVariable String date, 
        HttpSession httpSession) {
.......
 }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfW3K.png)

I want to remove this parameter (httpSession) from the document, and I need help。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Springfox won't show these values by default. The reason why `httpSession` is visible in your case, is because you added it by yourself as an implicit parameter:

```java
@ApiImplicitParam(name = "httpSession", value = "Session", required = false)
```

If you don't want the `httpSession` to pop up, remove that from your implicit parameters. Additionally, you don't even have to use `@ApiImplicitParam` in your case, you can use `@ApiParam`:

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "获取打卡信息", notes = "获取打卡信息")
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/{mPhone}/{mPassword}/{date}")
public @ResponseBody String getSignInfo(
        @ApiParam(value = "手机号", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="13268690268")
        @PathVariable String mPhone,
        @ApiParam(value = "密码", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="111111")
        @PathVariable String mPassword,
        @ApiParam(value = "日期", required = true, dataType = "String",defaultValue="2017-07-04")
        @PathVariable String date, 
        HttpSession httpSession) {
    // ...
 }
```